# Google Vertex AI Trained Model and Cloud Storage Region Settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have trained a vertexAI model with public data. I am trying to do a batch prediction with the trianed model using a local .csv file as source.

However, I encountered such an error.
"Source path must be in the same region as your model (us-central1)."

I have uploaded the  prediction source csv into the same bucket as my trained dataset. 
However I found out that my cloud storage bucket is located as `multi-region:US` while my trained model and .csvs are in `us-central1`

Is there any method for me to solve this issue or error, without opening a new cloud storage bucket? 
I tried copying the model to another region, but there is still no multi-region option.

Comment: Updates: \
Cloud Storage source path must be in the same region as your model (us-central1)

Comment: Hi @jaspercoleman, Is your issue resolved after given the same region ?

Comment: Not really. I failed to find a single region to copy the model to, that fulfills the multi-region cloud storage bucket settings. 

I wonder do I really have to set up a new bucket with a single region , as I need to went through horrible access rights to do so, which seems to be a slog.

@ArpitaShrivastava Thanks for following up though.

Comment: Can you try once removed prevent public access retention on cloud storage bucket. hopeful it will help you ?

Comment: Note that Google recommends to use regional bucket for training to minimize the latency/cost, and therefore to maximise the efficiency. Reconsider your process with that, and you will be regional and won't have this issue again.

Comment: I tried removing public access retention. 
It is still not working.

Comment: Did you follow this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/predict-batch) for this issue ?